# PHP Skip first row in CSV when uploading

Tags: php, mysql

i have this PHP code that uploads a CSV and inserts data into a database, once it has uploaded in the while loop it only selects one row from the CSV:

```
//do upload
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['dd_submission_form']['tmp_name']))
    {
        echo "<h3>" . "File ". $_FILES['dd_submission_form']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h3>";
        echo '<h3>Display file contents:</h3>';
        //readfile($_FILES['dd_submission_form']['tmp_name']);
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['dd_submission_form']['tmp_name'], "r");

    fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $sql="SELECT * from customer where directdebit_reference = '".$data[0]."' ";
        echo $sql;
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $customer=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
        if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0)
        {
            $sql2="INSERT into dd_submissions (customer_seq, dd_reference, sortcode, account_number, account_name, amount, bacs_code, invoice_no, title, initial, forename, surname, salutation_1, salutation_2, address_1, address_2, area, town, postscode, phone, mobile, email, notes) values ('".$customer["sequence"]."', '$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]', '$data[4]', '$data[5]', '$data[6]', '$data[7]', '$data[8]', '$data[9]', '$data[10]', '$data[11]', '$data[12]', '$data[13]', '$data[14]', '$data[15]', '$data[16]', '$data[17]', '$data[18]', '$data[19]', '$data[20]', '$data[21]', '$data[22]')";
            $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    print "<br><br><h3>Successfully Imported Clients</h3><br>";
```

Answer (score 4):

Just address the first row before the loop separately and do nothing with it to skip it.

`fgets($handle);` then your loop

Comment: @charlie Sorry, not sure. Pretty new to coding, Might be better off making a new question now, or trying the method vinodadhikary posted below. I just knew how to skip the first row from having this issue myself :p

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to make use of the `continue` keyword inside the `while` loop like follows:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  if ($i == 0) { $i++; continue; }
  ...
  $i++;
```

However, to be safe you have to make sure that the first row does not contain required data.

Comment: This will skip every row as yor $i++ is after the continue :)

Comment: @Trent, you're right, thanks.  It's so simple to overlook things isn't it? :)

Comment: it happens more frequently on the easier answers; stuff we probably copy and paste a thousand times a year from existing code

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you replace all of this code with a single call to mySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` query, which is designed to load CSV files directly into the database without needing all the PHP loops you're doing. It runs **massively** faster than doing it in a PHP loop.

Your customer field can be added easily using a subquery as part of the main `LOAD DATA INFILE` query.

Oh, and to answer the original question, it is also capable of skipping the first row (or rows) as part of the standard syntax.

See the mySQL manual page here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

**[EDIT]**

Your query would look roughly like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE
INTO TABLE dd_submissions
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROW
(
@dd_reference,
sortcode,
account_number,
account_name,
amount,
bacs_code,
invoice_no,
title,
initial,
forename,
surname,
salutation_1,
salutation_2,
address_1,
address_2,
area,
town,
postscode,
phone,
mobile,
email,
notes
)
SET
    customer_seq = SELECT sequence from customer where directdebit_reference = @dd_reference,
    dd_reference = @dd_reference
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem you are having might be because of the "1000", which is unnecessary anyways. An easy way to skip the first line is to do the following:

```
fgetcsv($handle) //skips the first line
while($data = fgetcsv($handle)) { //will process second line to end of file
  ...
}
```

However, you have a much bigger problem here. If your csv file looks like:

```
'; DROP TABLE customer #
```

Then $sql becomes

```
SELECT * from customer where directdebit_reference = ''; DROP TABLE customer #'
```

And now you have no customers. Look up SQL injection to learn how to make sure the queries that you are passing on to MySQL are safe.

Answer (score 0):

One probable reason of the breaking of the reading the rows from the csv file is that the data in your csv file might contain single or double quotes which breaks the sql query, so this problem can be solved by using the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function. So your new insert query would look like :

```
....
......

$sql2="INSERT into dd_submissions (customer_seq, dd_reference, sortcode, account_number, account_name, amount, bacs_code, invoice_no, title, initial, forename, surname, salutation_1, salutation_2, address_1, address_2, area, town, postscode, phone, mobile, email, notes) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string($customer["sequence"])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."', .......);
```

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Declare one variable before `while loop`:

```
 $row=1;
```

then in `while loop` put this condition:

```
 if($row==1){
   $row++; 
   continue;
 }
```